# Maxdop in Profiler

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, profiler, maxdop

Say I run a server side trace against a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance, which has `Maxdop = 1` in place, then I run the trace through `readtrace.exe` to get RML files for replay.

Does the replay preserve the instance-level setting of `Maxdop =`1 such that none of the queries will run parallel on a `maxdop = 0` server?

When I look at my trace, I see lots of events called 'Degree of Parallelism' with '1 - Select' in the EventSubClass. Does this force `maxdop = 1` for the queries when they are replayed against a different instance?

Answer (score 2):

The Degree of Parallelism event actually records the query parallelism in the BinaryData column, not the EventSubClass.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187943.aspx):

```
0x00000000, indicates a serial plan running in serial.
0x01000000, indicates a parallel plan running in serial.
>= 0x02000000 indicates a parallel plan running in parallel.
```

From my simple tests, RML or trace replay do not enforce the Degree of Parallelism event, which kind of makes sense, as this could be overridden by server-level maxdop or a local MAXDOP query hint.  SQL Server also normally decides whether to parallelise at query execution time depending on available resources.  This event is also collected *after* a query has started, and does not appear to be one of the events that does stuff in replay mode, like SQL:BatchStarted, eg if you step through your replay trace, nothing happens in this event.

HTH